# Short circuiting in Informix SQL

Tags: sql, informix, short-circuiting

Does Informix support short circuiting in SQL clause?
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE '0' IN (listOfValues) OR myTable.code IN (listOfValues)
```

where *listOfValues* is a list of codes specified by the user (where '0' means all codes).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes and no.

It depends on how you construct `listOfValues`. You cannot use a `?` placeholder for a list variable, but you can indeed write that SQL out long-hand and it will parse and do what you want. And you can call it short-circuiting if you wish.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE '0' IN ('0') OR myTable.code IN ('0')
```

will do what you require. But preparing

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE '0' IN (?) OR myTable.code IN (?)
```

and executing it with bind variables that point to lists will produce a run-time error.

All the [usual caveats](http://bobby-tables.com/) about why you should use bind variables still apply, you'll just need to find some other way to untaint (validate) your inputs.